# BoxView and RGBA values not showing

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

```
//model
public class ColorModel
{
    private Color _colorCard;

    public Color ColorCard
    {
        get { return _colorCard; }
        set { _colorCard = value; }
    }
    public int R
    {           
        get { return (int)(_colorCard.R * 255); }
        set { _colorCard = Color.FromRgba(  value,  _colorCard.G, _colorCard.B, _colorCard.A); }
    }

    //viewmodel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    private ObservableCollection<ColorModel> colorList;
       
       private ColorModel _colorModel;  

        public Color ColorCardView
        {
            get { return _colorModel.ColorCard; }
            set
            {
                if (_colorModel.ColorCard != value)
                {
                    _colorModel.ColorCard = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
               }
            }
        }

       public int RView
        {
            get { return _colorModel.R; }
            set
            {
                if (_colorModel.R != value)
                {
                    _colorModel.R = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my XAML code:

```
<BoxView Color="{Binding ColorCardView}" WidthRequest="100"HeightRequest="50"/>                                            
<Label FontSize ="Medium" Text="{Binding RView}"
```

The code successfully ran, but the BoxView is not showing up the color property bound to it and the R(fromrgba) value is not displaying also.

Comment: there is no `BoxView` in the code you posted

Comment: Apologies @jason. I have updated it.

Comment: Add to question an example of code that sets the color. I mean, the actual code that got run, that calls one of those property setters. Unless your code eventually calls `ColorCardView = ...`  or `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ColorCardView))`, xaml won't know it has changed. With the code you show, if you do `ColorCard = ...;` or `R = ...;` or `_colorCard = ...;`, xaml doesn't know the `ColorCardView` property changed.

Comment: I'm also concerned about `_colorModel.ColorCard`. That suggests the `ColorCardView` property is in a different class than `ColorCard`. If so, edit your code to **show which class ColorCardView is in.** Is there code somewhere that **changes colorModel's ColorCard directly**? ColorCardView does not magically know about such a change. If so, can say what to do, once you've edited the question with these changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new instance of `_colorModel` and then set it in your viewmodel constructor. You can refer to the sample code below:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{

        private ColorModel _colorModel { get; set; }


        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            _colorModel = new ColorModel()
            {
                ColorCard = Colors.Red,
                R = 255
            };
        }

        public Color ColorCardView
        {
            get { return _colorModel.ColorCard; }
            set
            {
                if (_colorModel.ColorCard != value)
                {
                    _colorModel.ColorCard = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public int RView
        {
            get { return _colorModel.R; }
            set
            {
                if (_colorModel.R != value)
                {
                    _colorModel.R = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                 new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
}
```

Finally, don't forget to set as the view's `BindingContext` like below:

```
BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
```

Comment: @Alexander, I have this in my constructor  already.

Comment: @HafizTijani You need add this to your post referring to [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And I also notice that you define `private  ObservableCollection<ColorModel> colorList` in your VM, what's that used for?

Comment: it is a field for my Collection property.  public ObservableCollection<ColorModel> ColorList
        {
            get => colorList;
            set { colorList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }

Comment: @HafizTijani I've updated my answer, it works on my side, you can refer to it.

Comment: @Thanks, Really appreciate. I